# Which of the following sets necessarily contain a multiple of 3

Tags: number-theory

[image]

As far as I understand binomial expansion for $\ n^{38}$ is a very long process. Is there any easier method to check whether when n=3m+1 or n=3m+2 $\ n^{38} -1 $is a multiple of 3?

Comment: You can use  modular congruences and  Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n^{19} $ is divisible by $3$, we are done.  Otherwise,  $n^{19} $ is congruent to $1$ or $-1$ modulo $3$.

Then $n^{38} = (n^{19})^2 \equiv (\pm 1)^2 = 1 \pmod{3} $, so $n^{38}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {3} $, so it is divisible by $3$.

Alternatively, a non-modular solution:

If $n^{19}$ is not a multiple of $3$, we have $n^{19}= 3m \pm 1$ for some integer $m $. Then
$$ n^{38} -1=(n^{19})^2-1=(3m \pm 1)^2 -1=(3m)^2 + 2 (\pm 1)(3m) +(\pm1)^2 -1 = 9m^2 \pm 6m +1-1=3 (3m^2 \pm 2m), $$
which is divisible by $3$.

The idea behind modular arithmetic is that if we only care about divisibility by three, we only need to keep track of the remainders when we perform such calculations, which greatly simplifies matters. You'll love it once you've learnt it!

Comment: havent studied modular congruences yet...will get back soon

Comment: To do this without modular congruences, write $n^{19} $ as $3m \pm 1$, and then take the binomial expansion of the *square* of that - a much shorter expression!

Comment: @Shagnik I was just going to suggest you edit your answer to reflect that approach. :-)

Comment: @Joffan good idea ;-)

Comment: Thank you...it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

The expansion is not too laborious

$$(3m+1)^{38}-1 = \sum_{i=1}^{38} \binom {38}i (3m)^{i} =3 \left(\sum_{i=1}^{38} \binom {38}i 3^{i-1}(m)^{i} \right)$$

Note that the number inside the bracket is an integer.

Or you can use Fermat's little theorem, for prime number $p$

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

So $$(3m+1)^{3-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

$$((3m+1)^2)^{19} \equiv 1^{19} \pmod 3$$

Comment: shouldn't the expansion start fom i=0?

Comment: @OsheenSachdev Yes I skipped a step, since the 0 term will give us $1$.

Comment: @OsheenSachdev No, see that I write $(3m+1)^38 -1$, so the $1$ from the expansion cancels out.

Comment: I got it...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that the answer is B by considering only $3$ cases:

- $\small n\equiv\color\red0\pmod3 \implies n^{19}\equiv\color\red0^{19}\equiv0\pmod3$
- $\small n\equiv\color\red1\pmod3 \implies n^{38}-1\equiv\color\red1^{38}-1\equiv1-1\equiv0\pmod3$
- $\small n\equiv2\pmod3 \implies n\equiv\color\red{-1}\pmod3 \implies n^{38}-1\equiv(\color\red{-1})^{38}-1\equiv1-1\equiv0\pmod3$